# Prepare for Wedo WRO

Tags: wedo

My son is 5 years old and completely hooked on to Wedo. I would like to unlock the possibilities for him to explore his area of interest. One such avenue can be to prepare for competitions like WRO. Please advise on any information about the competitions - what are the things that need to be learnt. Also any open resources available for preparing can help.

Answer (score 2):

LEGO has [this page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/competitions) which mentions World Robot Olympiad (WRO) and FIRST® LEGO® League (FLL).  There's a tag for FLL ([fll](/questions/tagged/fll)) on Bricks.SE so you [can see what other folks have asked about it](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fll).